# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reopen' (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm updating from a prerelease to Ember js 1.0.0.  I'm currently getting the title error for

```
Ember.State.reopen( {

    active: false,

    enter: function() {

        this.set('active', true);
    },

    exit: function() {

        this.set('active', false);
    }
});
```

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember states has been removed since this [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3191)

You can find it in [ember-states github repository](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states)